# questions regarding quote='' failed to handle the case of cell including ,

Tags: r

I imported the table as follows

```
newtable<-data.frame(read.table("data.csv",sep=",",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,quote=''),row.names=NULL)

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :  

 line 5165 did not have 16 elements
```

I checked the line 5165 of the original file, it has something like `ABC,ABD`  I already tried to use `quote=''` to handle this kind of scenario, but looks like it did not work.

> 26R   a - d   30C 30- S, CC, TS   330 30-Sv & Op  0C  0-I Se De   30  30-T U I    IN_SE   Information S   GF  G F NG  NG C C H
>   [image]

Comment: Please paste all of line 5165 from `data.csv` so we can see what might be wrong with it.

Comment: In addition to the line, also tell us your desired/expected result.

Comment: I have pasted the row that I have been referring to in the post. Since it does not allow me to attach the csv file, I just upload the screenshot for this specific row.

Comment: Your `D` column has commas, while you are specifying comma as a separator. The separator is probably `\t`?